# Admob Rewarded video ad events not called

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I have two activity. In both activity I am giving rewards for rewarded video. For first activity everything works fine. But In second activity  (same implementation) , but rewarded video events are not getting called. Ad is just loaded and shown but  nothing else (things in on rewarded event) is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue got resolved.

I implemented 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1' version and got an issue. I changed it back to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0' and its working fine. I still don't know the reason why it happened. But It got solved by this.